# Sending Emoji's to Telegram using MQL4 code

Tags: mql4

I am able to send plain text from mt4 to telegram in my MQL4 code. But I'm having trouble adding telegram emojis to my code.

Comment: Since this is not possible in mql4, I managed to pass the data to php and add the necessary emojis to telegram.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not possible in mql4, I managed to pass the data to php and add the necessary emojis to telegram.